# Python logging: access custom logger from several files

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

How can I declare a custom logger with custom logging method in the main.py and then use the same object (!) in all the files that main.py uses:

eg

```
#main.py
import logging
from additional import bar

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self)
        self.foo = None

    def log(self, message):
        apply_external_method(self.foo, message)
        print(message)

logger = logging.getLogger('the_only_logger')  # Should be CustomLogger
logger.foo = "foo"
```

And

```
# additional.py
logger = logging.getLogger('the_only_logger')  # Should be CustomLogger and foo should be set
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a custom Handler.

Comment: Define your custom logging in its own module and have every other module in your application import that module first,  before library modules that may otherwise initialize logging first and preempt what you are trying to do. I know that violates PEP-8 rules on import order. That's too bad.

Comment: I second @KlausD.  What are you acutally trying to do w.r.t. logging?  A custom handler or formatter might be more appropriate than subclassing `Logger`.

Comment: @Iguananaut I have several processes from multiprocessing (workers) that create logs, and I collect logs via Queue in the separate process to pass them to the server every n minutes. 

I need the same object for logger to store the same queue and APIManager objects in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Klaus D, I figured out I need to set CustomHandler, and I need to do only once, after that logger can be shared across files with logger = logging.getLogger('same-logger-name')

```
# main.py
import logging
from additional import foo


class CustomHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queue = queue
        print("Init", id(queue))
        super(CustomHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def emit(self, record):
        print("Log")
        print(self.format(record))


logger = logging.getLogger('2')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = CustomHandler("custom object")
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug('information')

foo()
```

and

```
# additional.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('2')


def foo():
    # will be printed with "Log" before it
    logger.debug('information from 2nd file')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you,
first, if you want to use a specific object you can add it to every constructor to get a logger object.
the second thing is you can make the logger write to a file and every file will create a new object but will write to the same file.

hope it's help(:

Comment: No, object must be the same